When does file system error "Superblock last mount time is in the future" occur?
At one of our customers we have a debian 7.8 system running that sometimes doesn't boot. The system is then waiting for user input to run fsck manually.
The boot screen halts with following info:

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
   (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck died with status 4
failed (code 4).
[....] An automatic file system check (fsck) of the root filesystem failed. A manual fsck must be performed, then the system restarted. The fsck should be performed in maintenance mode with the root filesystem moutned in read-only mode. ..
failed!
[....] The root filesystem is currently mounted in read-only mode. A maintenance shell will now be started. After performing system maintenance, press CONTROL-D
Terminate the maintenance shell and restart the system. ... (warning).
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue): _

I found that the wrong system time (broken CMOS battery) can be the cause of this problem. However when I try to simulate the problem on another pc running Debian 7.11, I can't reproduce the issue. I disconnected the CMOS battery, waited for a while and then this system booted completely without asking for manual fsck check.
What can cause the difference in behaviour of these two systems? Can it be the difference in operating system version of configuration? What triggers the system to stop booting and waiting for manual input?
What is the best way to boot the system completely without halting at half boot?
Replacing the CMOS battery is difficult because it is a remote system in a different country.

Different systems may have different let's say "Start Times" when the CMOS battery is disconnected. I remember very old ones defaulted to January 1, 1980, then some newer defaulted to e.g. January 1, 2000, so maybe your system defaults to something recent enough and thus the error is not triggered.

Interesting thought, however the default system time of the system with the error is 1 january 2014, the system that does boot has 31 december 2008.
